# Are there any websites that list common build orders?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, starcraft-protoss, sc2-build-order, starcraft-terran

I'm trying to compile a list of common (or at least good) build orders across all three races. Does anyone know of some websites where I can collect this data from? Thanks.

Comment: How self-serving would it be if I were to list [our](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359/what-build-order-should-i-use-for-zerg-in-starcraft-2/363#363) [own](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/875/what-are-the-popular-build-orders-for-protoss-in-starcraft-2/891#891) [site](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/918/what-are-the-popular-openings-builds-for-terran-in-starcraft-2/958#958)?

Comment: @Grace yes, but I'm looking for other pools of information (some diversity) than here too :)

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary if all the info you need is here @Bryan

Comment: @Ivo I'm looking less for descriptions of the build order strategy (which is what those three post primarily consist of), and more of the actual build order list. See this Liquidpedia build as example (click Show beside of Basic Build) http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Reactor_Hellion_Expand_%28vs._Zerg%29

Comment: Builds and openings in Starcraft 2, while well defined, are often the product of "tribal" knowledge.  You stand a much better chance of finding the information you want by asking a specific question here.  For example "What's a good ZvZ opening into muta?" Which I'm sure someone would mention the Diehilde build.  A Stackexchange site has many short comings, but collecting tribal information is actually one of its strengths.  If you're looking for a build: ASK for it.  If you're looking for a website, well I think you've found one: gaming.stackexchange.com

Comment: @tzenes Ultimately, I am collecting this information for a database I am trying to create for an application.  I don't have a specific build question to ask, but instead am just trying to collect as much information on common builds that I can find.  So there really is no specific question about a build here (hence the wiki, because I am looking for a list of resources).  And since "stub builds" seem to be taboo here, I am looking for resources that *do* contain "stub builds"

Comment: "Stub" builds are by no means taboo here, only on liquidpedia.  Teamliquid has a long tradition for holding their builds to the highest standards.  But I think you have a very different problem: what is a common build? Broodwars was around for a number years before builds were standardized.  In the intervening time period builds came and went rather rapidly.  Look at JulyZerg who brought about the Zerg Renaissance.  Prior to him there was only 3 Hatch, but after we see the myriad of builds which would later become standardized, 6 years after release.

Answer (score 2):

[Liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Main_Page) is a good one. It lists a number of build orders used by tournament players for the various races. It also suggests what build orders to use in different situations (TvT or TvP). I did find it lacking in in that it doesn't have a lot of build orders for team games.

Comment: Liquidpedia has a tradition of only recording established builds and often taking down what they call "stub" builds.  Their "stub" builds are really what you are likely looking for, however, they usually lack the information necessary to execute the build.

Comment: @tzenes Yes, this is more what I'm looking for, the actual listing of what to build at certain consumed food numbers, etc.

Comment: @Bryan then I'd be careful as stub build are usually removed by the moderators.

Answer (score 1):

[SC2 Builds](http://www.sc2builds.com/) exists for the sole purpose of showing people build orders. In addition, you can use [YABOT](http://www.sc2builds.com/resources.aspx) to play-test the build orders.