# 10-pylon vs 8-pylon

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

I usually build 8 probes, then a pylon, so I could keep building probes and not have to wait for the pylon to build (in 10-pylon you're stuck while the pylon is building).

Is one of these build better than the other?
[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/875/what-are-the-popular-build-orders-for-protoss-in-starcraft-2/891#891) states that most Protoss go 10-pylon.

Comment: That should read 9 pylon.  Its also a little dated as a lot of Protoss have been going 12 Gate since the 5 seconds change on Zealots

Comment: @tzens - 5 seconds change ?

Comment: in patch 1.1 zealots' build time was increased by 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

There was a fun poll about this [on Team Liquid](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=136582).

The issue with 8 Pylon is that you lose a few seconds of mining time down the line.   To make up for it you have to use your first Chrono Boost before the Pylon instead of after. This will lead to a temporary advantage that will cost you in the long run.  Outside of the early gateway play, this usually isn't worth it.

Comment: Early advantage or disadvantage...?

Comment: @Albort Early advantage, but late disadvantage

Comment: 9 Pylon 12 Gate is "standard" earlier pylon for an earlier gate is an option but it isn't standard. Waiting until 10 is supply blocking yourself which is bad and it gets your gate out later.

Comment: @Bravo 8 Pylon is still a well used technique amongst many higher level Protoss (it was a core part of Tester's 2 Gate).  I would say 8 Gate is about as standard as 12 Pool.  Both aren't as common as their n+1 relatives, but you run into both a lot more on the KR server than NA

Answer (score 1):

I've always done 9-pylon and have the pylon finish exactly as the 10th probe finishes.  I often have to wait 1 second between starting the pylon and having minerals to start the 10th probe.

Answer (score 0):

I've been practicing this a lot for Cannon rush openings. 8 pylon boost seems like it could maintain the mining pace of the 10 pylon if executed well. You'd lose a boost though that would've been used for building something else.