# Is 11th drone better than 9th drone overlord?

Tags: starcraft-2, sc2-build-order

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to spawn your first overlord at 9 or 10 supply?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5862/is-it-better-to-spawn-your-first-overlord-at-9-or-10-supply)

As Zerg, I can make an overlord after my 9th drone or after my 10th. If I make it after the 10th, I can build an extrator, a 11th drone then cancel  the extractor.

Does anyone have concrete facts comparing the 2 strategies? Is one better than the other? It doesn't have to be a large gap, just "This one is better by X minerals".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it better to spawn your first overlord at 9 or 10 supply?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5862/is-it-better-to-spawn-your-first-overlord-at-9-or-10-supply).  11 and 10 are both covered by this question/answer.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5862/is-it-better-to-spawn-your-first-overlord-at-9-or-10-supply/5871#5871).

In short, 11OL is worse by 1 or 4 minerals at the 2:15 marker, depending on how you do the extractor trick.

Comment: Alan usually we use close as duplicate in cases like this.